# Invoking thread function later

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I had a question in C?
Is it possible to create a thread and invoke the thread function later whenever it is required?
Probable using a thread_start routine whenever it is required.
Otherwise, if i use the pthread_create the thread will be created multiple times and have to be handled carefully. 
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your requirements a bit more clearer. Otherwise the only answer anyone can give to this is "yes, most likely it's possible"

Comment: Sure, just code the thread to wait for work and do the work when told.

Comment: Following up on @DavidSchwartz comment, you can use a condition variable and broadcast to it, or you can wait on I/O.  You can do it at the top of a loop so that it processes data or a chunk of work every time the condition variable is signaled or I/O completes.

Comment: In the current scenario i am creating the thread like this 
event_ind()
{
 pthread_t data_thread;
 if(0<pthread_create(&data_thread, NULL, work_thread_func, NULL))
     printf("thread creation successful");
 else
    pthread_join(data_thread, NULL);
}

So the pthread will br created everytime there is an event_indication.
Better i create the thread only once and invoke thread function whenever there is an event
and terminate it when the event indication stops.

Is there a better way to do handle this?

Comment: You might be looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can use semaphores, just block thread function in while loop:

```
    while(1){
        sem_wait(my_semaphore);
        code_that_needs_to_be_done_in_thread;
    }
```

..and whenever you need your thread,just simply signal it:

```
    sem_post(my_semaphore);
    ...
    other_code;
    sem_post(my_semaphore);
    ...
```